# Where does "it" come from in this example of ObjectSet<T>.SelectValue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
productQuery1.SelectValue<Int32>("it.ProductID");
```

How would I know what "it" means here?

Whole example from [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359146.aspx)

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    string queryString =
        @"SELECT VALUE product FROM 
            AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product";

    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery1 =
        new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString,
            context, MergeOption.NoTracking);

    ObjectQuery<Int32> productQuery2 =
        productQuery1.SelectValue<Int32>("it.ProductID");

    foreach (Int32 result in productQuery2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's more like `this`.

[It's a convention in query builder methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx).

> In a query builder method, you refer to the current ObjectQuery command by using an alias. By default, the string "it" is the alias that represents the current command...